# banner ad is placed over the second item of a recyclerview

Tags: android, admob

This is my `activity_main` layout, which is the navigation drawer, and includes the `main` activity layout, named `app_bar_main`.

```
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.navTheme"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have called the ad as (from my `MainActivity`):

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
      @Override
      public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
      }
    });
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

My activity is a `viewpager`, and first of which contains a `recyclerview`.
The problem is the ad is shown just at the end of the first item of the `recyclerview`, not at the end of the screen. 
What should I do?

**UPDATE** After moving my adview to recyclerview, like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent">

  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/rv_recycler_view"
      android:scrollbars="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
      xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/adView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:layout_margin="4dp"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      ads:adSize="BANNER"
      ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
  </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My adview is at the bottom of the screen, my last item in the recyclerview is always covered by the ad. So, what is the trick to make the last item visible?

Comment: So you can add Your Mobile Add at bottom of recycler view , not in activity

Comment: post xml which contains recyclerview in it

Answer (score 0):

You are not aligning properly your `RecyclerView` and `AdView`. Basically you should 'tell' your `RecyclerView` to be placed above `AdView`  and since your parent `ViewGroup` is `RelativeLayout` you can do that with: `android:layout_above="view_id"` :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/rv_recycler_view"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
         android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
         android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
         xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:id="@+id/adView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_margin="4dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
         ads:adSize="BANNER"
         ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```